# The LINQ expression 'Sum()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have the following query in Entity Framework Core:

```
var results = context.Packages.AsNoTracking()
  .Select(x => new {
    Result = x.Products
      .SelectMany(y => y.Definition.Conversions, (Product, Conversion) => new { Product = Product, Conversion = Conversion })
      .Where(y => y.Product.DefinitionId == y.Conversion.DefinitionId)
      .Select(y => new {
        Coefficient = y.Conversion.Coefficient,
        Price = y.Product.Price.Value,
      })
      .GroupBy(y => 1)
      .Select(y => new {
        Coefficient = y.Sum(z => z.Coefficient),
        Price = y.Sum(z => z.Price)
      })
    }).ToList();
```

When I run this query I get the message:

```
The LINQ expression 'Sum()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

What am I missing

Comment: There was an issue in 2.1 [Specific GroupBy + Sum is evaluated locally #12433](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12433) i wonder if this is related. are you sure you are 2.2 ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Entity Framework 2.2. I just checked ...